# Get the type of a given XML element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

How can I figure out the type of a given XML element with jQuery?

For example, if I want the type of the second child:

**XML:**

```
<xml>
  <a>a element</a>
  <b>b element</b>
  <c>c element</c>
</xml>
```

**JS:**

```
var node = $(xml).eq(2);
var nodeType = getNodeType(node);
if (nodeType == 'b') {
   alert('GOT IT');
}


function getNodeType($node) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think the example here should help: [http://api.jquery.com/children/](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `nodeName` on the element (not on the jQuery object).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/2cSpq/

```
var xml = "<xml><a>a element</a><b>b element</b><c>c element</c></xml>";

var node = $(xml).children().eq(1);
var nodeType = alert(getNodeType(node));
if (nodeType == 'b') {
   alert('GOT IT');
}


function getNodeType($node) {
   return $node[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();  <--- right here
}
```

I also used the [`children()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method to target the nested elements, which would make the `b` element at index `1`, not `2`.

The `[0]` extracts the node from the jQuery object, `.nodeName` gets the node's name, and `.toLowerCase()` ensures it is sent to you as the lower case letter you're testing for.